# Multi-server environment is causing problems in WordPress

Tags: server, hosting

I recently handed off a WordPress site I developed to an IT team that is in charge of my client's web environment. They aren't WordPress people and I don't have any access to the environment. There are currently issues as a result of the environment they are using, which I'll explain:

- Server A (Web server)

  - Domain name (http://example.com) points here, rewrites are made, and traffic is routed to either Server B or C.
- Server B (App server)

  - Running an ecommerce CMS. Traffic to http://example.com/shop is routed here
- Server C (WordPress server)

  - Running the WordPress site. Traffic to http://example.com/blog is routed here

Next, some important notes:

- The WordPress Address and Site Address in WP are set to http://example.com/blog.
- The WordPress database has been searched and replaced so all URLs are http://example.com/blog
- Pages and assets in the **frontend** are being served correctly

Despite these facts, there are links in the **backend** of WordPress that are still using the server's IP address URL. For example, all of the pagination controls in post/page lists.

Also, any kind of form in the backend is broken. For example, if I try to delete a plugin, the form which handles the delete button have the `POST` action mapped to `/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=delete-selected...` This of course means it's ignoring the `/blog/` subdirectory in the Site Address, which then 404s. I think this particular issue is a result of Server A trying to rewrite that request.

There are other problems, but they all boil down to WordPress seemingly not knowing exactly what its URL is. My opinion is that because of Server C's setup, it is causing the wrong URL to be used in places where the PHP is doing things like this:

`$current_url = set_url_scheme( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );`

`HTTP_HOST` uses the Host header, **if one is present**, otherwise it must grab the value from the server, which is currently the IP address.

**My question is...** how do we tweak this setup and fix these URL issues in WordPress?

Comment: Of note, you can't just do a text search replace on a database or export to change a WordPress sites URL, as it's stored in PHP serialised structures in some options, and these structures are corrupted if the new URL has a different length

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution!

http://www.iconwebsolutions.info/wordpress-admin-prevnext-page-links-still-pointing-to-the-old-site/

Open the file wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php

Search for ‘function pagination’
You will find below line of code to set the current url
$current_url = set_url_scheme( ‘http://’ . $_SERVER[‘HTTP_HOST’] . $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’] );

$current_url is built using $_SERVER[‘HTTP_HOST’] which will not work for the servers running under proxies
so change this URL or basically hardcode it with your server URL as below:

$current_url = set_url_scheme( ‘http://serverurl.com’ . $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’] );

Comment: Welcome. Please format your code.